# Fastest way to get all the string value of 4th column in a command output

Tags: text-processing

```
Item Name        Data     Price            Comment 
shoes            Nike     20               Expensive item
pencil                                     Cheap price
bag                                        Most expensive
```

The objective is to get the value of the 4th column taking the consideration of tab information for column 2 and 3.

With `awk '{print $4,$5}'`, I am getting the expected output but if I do it for second line the data is not correct.

Comment: What's the column separator?

Comment: the separator will be tab

Comment: The text in your question does not look like tab-separated values (spaces are too long in the last 2 rows), are you **sure** your input is tab-separated? If so please [edit] your question to show that, if not please [edit] your question to tell us what really separates your columns or if they're actually fixed width fields as they appear to be right now.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is tab-delimited and you want the 4th column, use `cut` with the option `-f 4`:

```bash
cut -f 4 file
```

The `cut` utility uses tab as its default delimiter.

Your `awk` command uses `awk`'s default field delimiter, which is any run of consecutive whitespace (tabs or spaces).  With `-F '\t'`, you change the input field delimiter of `awk` to a tab, see the `awk` way to do the same as the above `cut` command would be

```bash
awk -F '\t' '{ print $4 }' file
```

Using a slightly more "high-level" and TSV-aware tool such as Miller (`mlr`), you could even address the column by name:

```bash
mlr --tsv cut -f Comment file
```

This would read the data as TSV ("tab-separated values") and extract the `Comment` field for each input record (line).

("TSV-aware" means it knows that quoting a field allows the field to embed tabs and newlines, just as in CSV files, something that `awk` would not be able to do without some extra hand-holding.)

Comment: it does not work on my end using awk as per your suggestion it is showing me blank information.

Comment: @AdrianBautisat Could it be that the 4th tab-delimited field is empty and that it's the 5th field that is the `Comment` field? It difficult to see where in your example data the tabs are actually placed.

Comment: [root@master-node ]# lastlog
Username         Port     From             Latest
root             pts/0    192.168.234.1    Thu Dec 29 22:26:20 +0800 2022
bin                                                      **Never logged in**
[root@master-node script]# lastlog -u bin | awk -F 't' '{print $4}'
[root@master-node ] #

Comment: @AdrianBautisat If you have clarifications to your question, then please consider updating the question.

Comment: @AdrianBautisat Also, `lastlog` on the Linux systems that I have access to does not produce tab-delimited output.

Comment: thank you for your input you are right. If this is the case, I need to massage the output on my end to achieve the desired output.

Comment: @AdrianBautisat not necessarily but you do have to edit your question to tell us what your real input would be for us to help you write a tool to parse that input.

Comment: @AdrianBautisat I see in [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730023/fastest-way-to-get-all-the-string-value-of-4th-column-in-a-command-output#comment1384404_730025) that you used `awk -F 't' '{print $4}'` - that's an archaic way of setting the FS to `\t` and YMMV depending on which awk you use. If you want to set FS to `\t` then just do that: `awk -F '\t' '{print $4}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

I would start here by saying Regexes are your friend. Do you actually have 4 columns, and not five? You can quickly visualize columns by 1) converting header/body "word-spacing" to underscore and 2) converting tabs to commas or vertical bar (or some other suitable replacement:

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/\x0020/_/;' < file > tmp1
~$ cat tmp1
Item_Name   Data    Price   Comment 
shoes   Nike    20  Expensive_item
pencil          Cheap_price
bag         Most_expensive
```

#andthen:

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/\t/|/;'  < file > tmp2
~$ cat tmp2
Item_Name|Data|Price|Comment|
shoes|Nike|20|Expensive_item
pencil|||Cheap_price
bag|||Most_expensive
```

So really, to extract the fourth column (zero-index = 3) the code at this point simplifies to:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put .split("|").[3] // "";' tmp2
```

The above code will retain blank (empty) lines; to remove blank (empty) lines use the following:

```
~$ raku -ne '.put with .split("|").[3];' tmp2
```

Once you're confident that you have the correct column, simply run the code immediately above on your original file from the get-go, with the parameter `.split("\t")` i.e. splitting on `tab`.

Sample Output (original file, splitting on `\t`):

```
Comment
Expensive item
Cheap price
Most expensive
```

[https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#\t_and_\T](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#%5Ct_and_%5CT)
https://raku.org